# Como puedo agregar mas caracteres a utl_file.put_line

Tags: sql, oracle, archivo

estoy trabajando con `utl_file.put_line` pero solo me permite ingresar `1023bytes`, pero requiero tener mas `3000 caracteres`.

no se envia el reporte al correo , si envio 1024 caracteres, no hay problema, pero si envio más, dice que se ejecuto pero no envia al correo nada

Comment: bytes no es lo mismo que caracteres. Deberías intentar y agregar que error te da (ORA-XXX). ¿Qué tipo de caracteres?¿solo ASCII o acentos y simbolos especiales?

Comment: debo tener caraceteres especiales, no me sale ningun error

Comment: si no te sale ningún error por qué no has podido?

Comment: porque no se envia el reporte al correo

Comment: No será le problema el envío al correo?

Comment: no, porque si envio 1024 caracteres, no hay problema, pero si envio mas, dice que se ejecuto pero no envia al correo nada

Comment: ¿estás seguro que tu BD es mysql? Porque hasta donde sé `utl_file.put_line` es de la BD Oracle

Comment: la BD es de oracle